# How to access JSON object key and value in ReactJS

Tags: json, reactjs

Goal is to access the key and value from JSON data in ReactJS.

Currently this value={this.state.myData} returns following JSON format data:

```
"list":[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "first_name": "FirstName",
    "last_name": "LastName"
  },
  "address:"{
    "street": "123",
    "City":   "CityName",
    "State": "StateName"
  },
  "other_info": []
]
```

UI structure:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  contstructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      myData: "",
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <td>{myData.id}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>first_name</th>
            <td>{myData.first_name}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix for the issue was the data type was a string from the return response. And to access values in the object it needed to be converted from string to object. JSON.parse() did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract `myData` from state before trying to use it in your `render()` function. You can do this using this line of code: `const {myData} = this.state;`. You can also do something like `const myData = this.state.myData;`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            myData: {
                "list": [
                    {
                        "id": "1",
                        "first_name": "FirstName",
                        "last_name": "LastName",
                        "address": {
                            "street": "123",
                            "City": "CityName",
                            "State": "StateName"
                        },
                        "other_info": []
                    }]
            }
        }
    };

    render() {
        // Extract myData from this.state.
        const {myData} = this.state;

        return(
            <div className="container">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th><td>{myData.id}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>first_name</th><td>{myData.first_name}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: tried this, no luck yet. by the way, one thing to point out that this.state.myData returns json data only after clicking the "Get" button. And not at the time of page got loaded first time. 
also tried this and it didn't work, to iterate over this json array. {this.state.myData.map(list) =>(
<td>{list}</th>
)}

Answer (score 0):

Since list is an array try doing `list[0].id`. In this way you'll be able to access 1st object of list:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            myData: {
                "list": [
                    {
                        "id": "1",
                        "first_name": "FirstName",
                        "last_name": "LastName",
                        "address": {
                            "street": "123",
                            "City": "CityName",
                            "State": "StateName"
                        },
                        "other_info": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    };

    render() {
        // Do not store this.state in a variable. it's bad coding habits

        return(
            <div className="container">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <td>{this.state.myData.list[0].id}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>first_name</th>
                        <td>{this.state.myData.list[0].first_name}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: not working yet. few things to clarify. 
this.state.myData returns that json data only after clicking the "Get" button.
And not at the time of page got loaded first time.
By pointing like this {this.state.myData.list[0].id} wouldn't point to the key/value.
However, when I tried {this.state.myData[1]} it points only to first letter of the value.
May be it needs to be access by using .map() functions so that it can iterate over the array?

Comment: you should put curly braces for the key-values in list and make it as a single JSON object as shown above in code

Comment: did exactly like it’s indicated in your code - and it didn’t point to that first value.
sorry, may be i’m not following you when you said place curly braces around the list